# How to fix this npm problem in Laravel 10 on Linux?

Tags: php, node.js, linux, npm, laravel-10

I'm in pop os 23.04, using a fresh Laravel project and following the Laravel documentation. I was trying to install the breeze starter kit. I tried nodejs installed by binaries and by nvm, but I can't go on because of the error in the npm.

I'm using Pop!_OS 23.04 for a fresh Laravel project, following the Laravel documentation. I attempted to install the Breeze starter kit using both Node.js installed via binaries and NVM, but I encountered an error with npm.

I executed the following commands:

```
php artisan breeze:install 
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev
```

However, I received the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code EPERM
> npm ERR! syscall symlink
> npm ERR! path ../autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer
> npm ERR! dest /media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer
> npm ERR! errno -1
> npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer' ->
> ```
>
> '/media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer' ->
> '/media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer']
> {
> npm ERR!   errno: -1,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
> npm ERR!   path: '../autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer',
> npm ERR!   dest: '/media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer'
> npm ERR! }
>
> ```
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user.
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/luzkramer/.npm/_logs    /2024-01-12T19_43_19_456Z-debug-0.log
> ```

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: yes i did and i tried to change the the permission. i used sudo chmod -R 755 * but nothing happened

Comment: Try running npm with the npm install --no-bin-links, which tells npm not to create any symlinks.

Comment: i tried the npm install --no-bin-link and this error appeared:                                                           npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/esbuild
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/errors:932
npm ERR!   const err = new Error(message);
npm ERR!               ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: /home/luzkramer/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node /media/luzkramer/HDD/codes/PHP/laravel/test/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild --version... the error code is bigger.